# Swagger and swagger.json location

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I managed to put together a swagger implementation with my java web service as a servlet declared in my web.xml.  Now I'm to the point of adding meaningful annotations and everything is fine.  However, in attempting to then implement swagger-ui to put a pretty face/functionality on it - I quickly realized how little I really understand how the process all works.  For instance, I have no problem generating a swagger.json from a usability standpoint - i.e., I can view it through the browser where I expect it, but at no time can I actually find a physical manifestation of the swagger.json in my project directory.  Does/can that make sense?

Comment: Which framework are you using? (E.g. Springfox, JAX-RS, ...)

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that: JAX-RS